# SailsJS test if process is already running

Tags: javascript, sails.js

say I have a long task that starts running when a person connects to `InitializeDB`. (Of course with authorization in the future, but left that out for now).

```
'post /initializeDB':'OrderController.initializeAll',
```

Now the problem is: the initialize function should never be run twice. - I know ideally I set up a taskmanager which just starts a task in the background which I could poll.
However for current simplicity, (and to show a proof of concept) is it possible for a sails route to "know" that another connection/route is already running? So that if I connect twice to `/initializeDB` it won't try to initialize the database twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable in your controller - just toggle it to `true` when the process is running, something like that. So, in OrderController.js:

```
var initializeRunning = false;

module.exports = {
    initializeAll: function(req, res) {
        // return benign result if already running
        if (initializeRunning) {
            return res.send({alreadyRunning: true});
        }
        // start running
        initializeRunning = true;
        // using setTimeout as a stand-in for a long async process
        setTimeout(function() {
            // finished the process
            res.send({complete: true});
            // if you want to allow this method to run again later, unset your toggle
            initializeRunning = false;
        }, 3000);
    },
};
```